# Unity3D which collider should be used around a capsule collider

Tags: unity-game-engine, collider

I tried everything and wasted whole 2 days on this matter but still failure.

Please see the image below.

[image]
[image]

I just want Object A to stick with Object B and do not drop (Object A around Object B obviously) (I don't want to freeze constraints aswell)

Object B has a capsule collider. Which collider should i use to get this working smoothly?

Answer (score 0):

B must to have capsule or **cylinder collider**

A must to have **mesh collider**.